# Возможно ли линейное безусловное программирование в реальных задачах?

Tags: алгоритм

Речь не о банальном Hello world, а о более серьезных вещах и алгоритмах. Одно время изучал БрейнФак, в котором отсутствуют условные переходы. Еще тогда, у меня возникла мысль, что любую (или большинство) программ можно преобразовать к линейному виду, то есть удалить из нее все условные переходы.

Comment: Видимо нет. Для начала попробуйте прочесть файл посимвольно.

Comment: Цикл - это на самом деле "синтаксический сахар" для условных и безусловных переходов. Так что даже если формально if'ов не будет, условные переходы будут скрыты за циклическими операторами.

Comment: @insolor, обратите внимание, что **формально** будут **только while**.

Если же опустится ниже, то **только if и goto**

Comment: все таки термин "линейное программирование" имеет другое и давно устоявшееся значение

Comment: @avp,

> Еще тогда, у меня возникла мысль, что любую (или большинство) программ можно преобразовать к линейному виду, то есть удалить из нее все *условные переходы*.

если уж автор упомянул условные переходы, тогда нужно "опуститься ниже" и убирать и while тоже.

Comment: @insolor, по этому поводу я уже сказал, что не получится. 

Вообще, бредовый вопрос.

Comment: #Нет!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Отвечаю на комментарий:

> Цикл - это на самом деле "синтаксический сахар" для условных и безусловных переходов. Так что даже если формально if'ов не будет, условные переходы будут скрыты за циклическими операторами.

Условные переходы можно не только циклами и if'ами делать. Можно использовать логические операторы && и ||, а также тернарный оператор "?:":

```
if(x==5) DoSomething();
```

можно заменить на такие варианты:

```
x==5 && DoSomething();
x!=5 || DoSomething();
x==5? DoSomething(): 0;
```

Только тут у них должны быть числовые возвращаемые значения. Если их нет, можно написать так:

```
x==5 && (DoSomething(), 0);
x!=5 || (DoSomething(), 0);
x==5? (DoSomething(), 0): 0;
```

---

Также ветвления можно реализовать через массивы функций из двух элементов. Вместо

```
if(isBlendEnabled) glEnable(GL_BLEND);
else glDisable(GL_BLEND);
```

можно сделать так:

```
//Где-то в заголовочном файле
const decltype(&glDisable) glDisEnable[2]={&glDisable, &glEnable};
...
//В коде
glDisEnable[isBlendEnabled](GL_BLEND);
```

---

А ещё можно булевые значения использовать в вычислениях:

```
if(x==5) y=14;
else y=0;
```

заменим на

```
y=14*(x==5);
```

И как вам такая функция определения знака?

```
int sign(int x) {return (x>0)-(x<0);}
```

На смайлик похоже.

Comment: Тернарный оператор или сокращенное вычисление булевых выражений - это уже ветвление.

А вот выражения вида y=14*(x==5); ветвлений не содержат, поэтому их можно использовать в критических по скорости местах программы.

Comment: >Тернарный оператор или сокращенное вычисление логических выражений - это уже ветвление. Да и укорочение записи в ущерб читаемости - от лукавого.

 Я о нём и пишу, как о способе скрыть ветвления. Так же, как и логические операции.

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю что нет. Ибо где-то видел/слышал/встречал теорему, которая утверждает, что любой алгоритм можно свести к 3-м управляющим операторам: цикл, условный переход и безусловный переход (в общем случае злосчастный `goto`, а в частном собсно переход к следующему оператору).

Теорема не доказывается в случае отсутствия условного оператора.

Comment: Если основательно постараться, то можно обойтись только **while** и вызовом функций (а может и без функций получится). 

По крайней мере **if** легко моделируется **while**-ом.

Comment: @avp, условные переходы могут иметь разную форму. Завершение цикла при определенном условии - это тоже условный переход. Условный переход - это больше абстрактное понятие.

Comment: Ну, пошутил я  (хотя, в каждой шутке есть доля шутки), а все почему-то бред, навеянный брейнфаком начали обсуждать.

Comment: @avp Ну условные переходы можно реализовать вызовами функций (при ленивых вычислениях). Основы лябда-исчисления, однако.